# Can't load image taken by 4S but can 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

My application receive images from a `UIImagePickerController` and when the image comes from a 5S I can properly load the image in quick view in debug, however if the image comes from a 4S I cannot view it and my application does not properly work.

Here is my code for the `UIImagePickerController`

```
- (IBAction)scanButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.sourceType = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if (_imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

         //_imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        _imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0); //This slots the preview exactly in the middle of the screen by moving it down 71 points
        _imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = translate;

        CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 1.333333, 1.333333);
        _imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = scale;

        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
        _overlay = [[CameraOverlay alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
        [_overlay.shootButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takePhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_overlay.cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelPhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_overlay.flashButton addTarget:self action:@selector(flashButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        _imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = _overlay;

    }

    _imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
    _imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    [self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

And my didFinish method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    _image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    _pickerDismissed = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

When I view `_image` from a 5S I can load the image, but from a 4S I cannot.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: The quick look thing could be a limitation of hardware - Could you give more information about the ways your app "doesn't properly work?" On the 4s? What are you doing with the image later on?

Comment: As a side note I can save the image to photos and it saves fine, but when working with the image in code and performing operations on it, it is as if it doesn't exist. Well for starters the image doesn't seem to work right off the bat. I am using OpenCV to find a business card in the image and some other operations. When the image comes from the 5S I can load the quick view data, but on the 4S I cannot and it seems the image from the 4S is "tainted" not allowing OpenCV to work properly..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weird, try a different iPhone 4S